# Setting Up Annotation Driven Transactions in Spring in @Configuration Class

Tags: java, spring, configuration, transactions, spring-transactions

So in the latest version of Spring we are able to use the `@Configuration` annotation to setup our configurations for Spring. Now in JavaConfig it is possible to use the `@AnnotationDrivenTx` ([@AnnotationDrivenTx Reference Link)](http://static.springsource.org/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch07.html) annotation to setup transactions in our Config class. But since JavaConfig has been decommissioned I was wondering if anyone knew how to setup something similar without JavaConfig and without needing to add anything to the `application-context.xml`. Here is what I basically have for my Config class

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("config/application-context.xml")
public class Config {

     public @Bean DataSource dataSource() {
           //get and return datasource
     }

     public @Bean Service1 getService1() {
          //return service1Impl
     }
}
```

And I'd like to make `Service1` transactional. If anyone has any ideas on how to do this or if this is just not possible please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can now use `@EnableTransactionManagement`.

See this post for more details: http://blog.springsource.com/2011/06/10/spring-3-1-m2-configuration-enhancements/

Answer (score 3):

It seems like it isn't possible according to [this forum post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=90960):

> there may be a more first-class
>   mechanism for enabling
>   annotation-driven TX in `@Configuration`
>   classes in Spring 3.1, but in the
>   meantime, the recommended approach is
>   to use `@ImportResource` to include a
>   snippet of XML that declares
>   `<tx:annotation-driven/>`

Wait: but you seem to have an XML context anyway. Why not add `<tx:annotation-driven/>` to it and use [`@Transactional`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)?

Comment: I ended up going this route. Would've been cool to do it the other way. Oh well.

Comment: I too have been fighting to migrate a Spring 2.5 JavaConfig project to Spring 3. I appreciate the better integration, but many conveniences are gone.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/17/spring-3-1-m1-featurespec. Spring 3.1's FeatureSpecification classes such as TxAnnotationDriven are designed to solve exactly the problem described above.