# Spring - No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications

I get this error when trying to invoke "persist" method to save entity model to database in my Spring MVC web application. Can't really find any post or page in internet that can relate to this particular error. It seems like something's wrong with EntityManagerFactory bean but i'm fairly new to Spring programming so for me it seems like everything is initialized fine and according to various tutorial articles in web.

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.5.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="wymysl.Controllers" />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="wymysl.repositories"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="wymysl.beans" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="wymysl.Validators" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator"/>

    <bean id="passwordValidator" class="wymysl.Validators.PasswordValidator"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
        <property name="username" value="system" />
        <property name="password" value="polskabieda1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:./META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/*" location="/resources/css/" cache-period="31556926"/>
</beans>
```

RegisterController.java

```java
@Controller
public class RegisterController {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    PasswordValidator passwordValidator;

    @InitBinder
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(passwordValidator);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String register(Person person) {
        return "register";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String register(@ModelAttribute("person") @Valid @Validated Person person, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "register";
        } else {
            entityManager.persist(person);
            return "index";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As the error says, there is no transaction. Annotate the register method with `@Transaction`.

Comment: @Rohit very informing

Answer (score 509, accepted):

I had the same problem and I annotated the method as `@Transactional` and it worked.

UPDATE: checking the spring documentation it looks like by default the PersistenceContext is of type Transaction, so that's why the method has to be transactional (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html):

> The @PersistenceContext annotation has an optional attribute type,
>   which defaults to PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION. This default is
>   what you need to receive a shared EntityManager proxy. The
>   alternative, PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED, is a completely
>   different affair: This results in a so-called extended EntityManager,
>   which is not thread-safe and hence must not be used in a concurrently
>   accessed component such as a Spring-managed singleton bean. Extended
>   EntityManagers are only supposed to be used in stateful components
>   that, for example, reside in a session, with the lifecycle of the
>   EntityManager not tied to a current transaction but rather being
>   completely up to the application.

Comment: If a method without the `@Transactional` annotion calls a method with the `@Transactional` annotation in the same classfile, you also will be struck by this error (that's what I was facing).

Comment: I annotated the service class with `@Transactional`, that also works. Not sure if it's the right way to go but it seems like it's working fine...

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning is that this annotation should be used for public method as it doesn't work otherwise.

Comment: But why do I need to annotate the method as @Transactional, what will change?

Comment: @NishantTanwar you can read all data, i.e. data won't change while reading, but if you are doing something that changes data, you have to make sure the query/process you are invoking is the only thing that is changing data to maintain the ACID property of database.

Comment: Remember, please, that @Transactional works on public methods only.

Comment: I had a strange issue, that the annotation of the method didn't work, but the annotation of the service solved the issue.

Comment: @Lokesh: Annotate calling method with `@Transactional` as well. Or make sure you call from a different class (or break up the service in smaller services, so you do call the method at a different class).

Comment: FYI this needs the javax.transaction.Transactional annotation (not the Spring one).

Comment: I am facing this issue with a method (inside a service) that called both the Delete methods from the repository and a couple of Save methods. The saves worked fine and this error showed up only when calling delete. Why is that? The solution does not work and the answer does not contemplate the reasons as to why Repository delete methods are treated differently from the rest.

Comment: Alternatively, programmatically, use [TransactionTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46415060/3779853)

Comment: incase your wondering which transactional. `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`

Answer (score 142):

I got this exception while attempting to use a deleteBy custom method in the spring data repository. The operation was attempted from a JUnit test class.

The exception does not occur upon using the `@Transactional` annotation at the JUnit class level.

Comment: I was in the same situation, instead of annotating the test-class I annotated the service method so it trickled down even if it wasn't a test.

Comment: `@Transactional` on a class-level can mask possible test problems that manipulate different transactions in your services.

Comment: I used `@Trasactional` on the repository method since its the place where I am actually interacting with the database and its working fine.

Comment: I had this issue when trying to 'deleteBy'. I changed the method to 'delete' and passed the whole object as argument.

Comment: faced this issue while foolowing chad derby's tutorial . He taught that by default jpa has @transactional at service level so we didn't need to add it here. But in case of deletion we actually need to while using entityManager.remove(object)

Answer (score 35):

This error had me foxed for three days, the situation I faced produced the same error. Following all the advice I could find, I played with the configuration but to no avail.

Eventually I found it, the difference, the Service I was executing was contained in a common jar, the issue turned out to be AspectJ not treating the Service instantiation the same. In effect the proxy was simply calling the underlying method without all the normal Spring magic being executed before the method call.

In the end the @Scope annotation placed on the service as per the example solved the issue:

```
@Service
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
@Transactional
public class CoreServiceImpl implements CoreService {
    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public final <T extends AbstractEntity> int deleteAll(Class<T> clazz) {
        CriteriaDelete<T> criteriaDelete = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createCriteriaDelete(clazz);
        criteriaDelete.from(clazz);
        return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaDelete).executeUpdate();
    }

}
```

The method I have posted is a delete method but the annotations affect all persistence methods in the same way.

I hope this post helps someone else who has struggled with the same issue when loading a service from a jar

Comment: Adding `@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)` to the DAO class which implements an interface is really important. I spent the whole day to figure out this error and your solution is the only one works. Thank you very much!

Comment: One L’annotation from your answer has just saved me probably around 3 days. I have just experienced the real power of edenema. Дякс.

Answer (score 22):

boardRepo.deleteByBoardId(id);

Faced the same issue. GOT *javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread*

I resolved it by adding **@Transactional** annotation above the controller/service.

Answer (score 22):

You need to add @Transactional to your methode

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 20):

Adding the `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` annotation at the class level for the test class fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Be aware that this will open a read-write transaction for every method call from outside the class. This might not be what you want, especially in high load situations. You might want to think about adding the annotation to the problematic method instead of the class.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same error because I switched from XML- to java-configuration.

The point was, I didn't migrate `<tx:annotation-driven/>` tag, as Stone Feng suggested.

So I just added `@EnableTransactionManagement` as suggested here
[Setting Up Annotation Driven Transactions in Spring in @Configuration Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722310/setting-up-annotation-driven-transactions-in-spring-in-configuration-class), and it works now

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and I added `tx:annotation-driven` in `applicationContext.xml` and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error when accessing an already  transactional-annotated method from a non-transactional method within the same component:

```
Before:
    @Component
    public class MarketObserver {
        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "maindb")
        private EntityManager em;

        @Transactional(value = "txMain", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
        public void executeQuery() {
          em.persist(....);
        }


        @Async
        public void startObserving() {
          executeQuery(); //<-- Wrong
        }
    }

    //In another bean:
     marketObserver.startObserving();
```

I fixed the error by calling the executeQuery() on the self-referenced component:

```
Fixed version:
    @Component
    public class MarketObserver {
        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "maindb")
        private EntityManager em;

        @Autowired
        private GenericApplicationContext context;

        @Transactional(value = "txMain", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
        public void executeQuery() {
          em.persist(....);
        }


        @Async
        public void startObserving() {
          context.getBean(MarketObserver.class).executeQuery(); //<-- Works
        }
    }
```

Comment: really works. Seems that invocation of the Transactional method from another thread requires context.getBean(....).

Comment: For the: `Calling method AA` that calls `method BB with @Transactional`, `AA` have to have `@Transactional` too... \
Idk why we need that, cuz I really dont need that in `AA` (especially when multi TransactionManager involved). \
Idk what mechanism Spring uses in @Transaction makes this answer work. \
(& Idk why in some other cases @Transaction in AA may not needed.)

Comment: Also, for a similar mechanism, I could got away with that Error by the following:: \

If I Separate & Externalized the methods: \
`method AA with no @Transactional` stays in one `class UU` & \
**`method BB with @Transactional` is put into another `@Component class VV`** \
`UU` have `VV` by `@Autowired` & `UU.AA` invoke `VV.BB` -> then it works.

Answer (score 4):

Just a note for *other* users searching for answers for thie error. Another common issue is:

> You generally cannot call an `@transactional` method from within the same class.

*(There are ways and means using AspectJ but refactoring will be way easier)*

So you'll need a calling class and class that holds the `@transactional` methods.

Answer (score 4):

I already had the `@Transactional` but still wasn't working. Turns out I had to get rid of ***parallelism*** to make it work.

If you are doing things in parallel, ***DON'T***.

Answer (score 3):

If you have

```
@Transactional // Spring Transactional
class MyDao extends Dao {
}
```

and super-class

```
class Dao {
    public void save(Entity entity) { getEntityManager().merge(entity); }
}
```

and you call

```
@Autowired MyDao myDao;
myDao.save(entity);
```

you won't get a Spring TransactionInterceptor (that gives you a transaction).

This is what you need to do:

```
@Transactional 
class MyDao extends Dao {
    public void save(Entity entity) { super.save(entity); }
}
```

Unbelievable but true.

Comment: Same for opposite - if you override a `@Transactional` method without `@Transactional`, even if you call super, it will fail (seems logical in this case, though)

Answer (score 3):

Without @Transactional annotation you can achieve the same goal with finding the entity from the DB and then removing that entity you got from the DB.

CrudRepositor -> void delete(T var1);

Answer (score 2):

For us, the problem came down to same context settings in multiple configuration files.  Check you've not duplicated the following in multiple config files.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:/module.properties"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="...." />
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error code when I used `@Transaction` on a wrong method/actionlevel.

```
methodWithANumberOfDatabaseActions() { 
   methodA( ...)
   methodA( ...)
}

@Transactional
void methodA( ...) {
  ... ERROR message
}
```

I had to place the `@Transactional` just above the method `methodWithANumberOfDatabaseActions()`, of course.

That solved the error message in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the mode from

```
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"
transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

to make this work

Answer (score 1):

This helped us, maybe it can help others in the future. `@Transaction` was not working for us, but this did:

`@ConditionalOnMissingClass("org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager")`

Answer (score 1):

Before processing entity just trigger detach on the entity then  do the operation on that entity like below

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SpringDataRestConfig {

    EntityManager entityManager;

    @HandleBeforeSave  // update or Patch
    @HandleBeforeCreate //Post
    public void handlePersonSave(Employee employee) {
        entityManager.detach(employee);
        // do the operation on the entity
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue for days and nothing I found anywhere online helped me, I'm posting my answer here in case it helps anyone else.

In my case, I was working on a microservice being called through remoting, and my @Transactional annotation at the service level was not being picked up by the remote proxy.

Adding a delegate class between the service and dao layers and marking the delegate method as transactional fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I executed the Spring JPA `deleteAll()` method from Junit test cases. I simply used the `deleteInBatch()` & `deleteAllInBatch()` and its perfectly works. We do not need to mark `@Transactional` at the test cases level.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same issue as I had, I was calling a public method `method1` from within another class.
`method1` then called another public method `method2` within the same class.
`method2` was annotated with `@Transactional`, but `method1` was not.
All that `method1` did was transform some arguments and directly call `method2`, so no DB operations here.

The issue got solved for me once I moved the `@Transactional` annotation to `method1`.

Not sure the reason for this, but this did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this in a test, you can use [`@DataJpaTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html) or `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase`.

Answer (score 0):

It's like you are using the shared EntityManager when you are getting it Autowired so for persisting spring tells that this EntityManager bean is a shared bean and for persisting it needs a hold of this bean till the data persist doesn't get completed so for that we have to use @Transactional so that it gonna start and commit the persistence in a transaction so the data or operation gets completely saved or get rollback completely.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error but with a 'remove' call since it dealt with a `deleteByEntityId()` method in the Spring Data repository.

The error was resolved by explicitly annotating the `deleteByEntityId()` method in the `CustomEntityRepository` with `@Transactional`. It would instruct Spring to wrap the delete method within a transactional context when invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the jakarta.transaction.Transactional(or javax.transaction.Transactional for earlier java versions) on the service class method alone would solve the issue as the all the processing done inside said method would be within the transaction.

Answer (score -1):

Calling the repository method was being called within a class with @Component, taking that method out of that class and placing it inside another with @Service worked.

Comment: Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer.