# No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

This error occurs at `this.itemRepository.deleteAll()` when `sampleTest()` method is run.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@SpringBootTest
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Rollback(false)
public class ScheduleTests {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduleTests.class);

    @Autowired
    private ScheduleRepository scheduleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository itemRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ItemQualifierRepository itemQualifierRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MappingRepository mappingRepository;

    @BeforeAll
    public void setUp() {
        restoreInitialData();
        LOGGER.info("Initial data restored");
    }

    @Test
    public void sampleTest() {
        File feed = new File("target/test-classes/TestFeedOK.json");
        Feed.ingest(feed);
        LOGGER.info("Feed {} ingested", feed.getName());
    }

    private void restoreInitialData() {
        this.itemRepository.deleteAll();
        this.mappingRepository.deleteByTableName("event");
    }
}
```

Adding `@Transactional` annotation to `restoreInitialData()` does not solve the problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32552558/3536552

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: did you try making the whole class `@Traansactional`?

Comment: @pvpkiran Yes I tried but it didn't help

Comment: which version of spring boot are you using. because in the latest version `AutoConfigureTestDatabase` is deprecated

Comment: @pvpkiran I use `2.0.0.M5`

Comment: I think the problem is `restoreInitialData` is called from setup which is a `@BeforeAll` method. May be spring hasnt stepped in at that point to have a transaction created. Just change this to `@BeforeEach` and check and also with `@Transactional`. Just a guess

Comment: @pvpkiran Indeed when I changed `@BeforeAll` to `@BeforeEach` test runs without an error, however I would like `restoreInitialData()` method to be invoked just once.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is `restoreInitialData` is called from `setup` which is a @BeforeAll method. 
  Spring hasn't stepped in at that point to have a transaction created. Just change this to @BeforeEach and check and also with @Transactional.
   If you want something to be executed only once. Try this approach

```
private static boolean setUpIsDone = false;
.....
public void setUp() {
    if (setUpIsDone) {
        return;
    }
    // do the setup
    setUpIsDone = true;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 0):

By default Spring provides implementations of `Interface` and `Class` but with the test environment spring expect you to provide its implementation. So use following code to provide `EntityManager` implementation.

**PersistenceJPAConfig.java**

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment; 

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.example.db.model" });

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        String driverClassName = environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.driverClassName");
        String url = environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.url");
        String username = environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.username");
        String password = environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.password");

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings","false");
        return properties;
    }
}
```