# How to delete Objects in a Tree-like structure in JPA?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

My application can store folders and files, every folder can have some subfolders and got an `parent_id` attribute pointing to his parent folder. The Code for this JPA-Object is shown below, also a screenshot from the database table.

Now I want to add a delete feature that deletes a Folder with all contents.
For example delete `SubFolder-3` should delete SubFolder4, -5, -6 and itself.

I tried it with Cascade.Type=REMOVE on the `parent`attribute, and added `@transactional` to my delete method in repository. But i get this error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "cloud_folder" violates foreign key constraint "fk715hn6f0nslmk97oftbbtm0ab" on table "cloud_folder"
  Detail: Key (id)=(5) is still referenced from table "cloud_folder".
```

Folder Object:

```
@Entity
public class CloudFolder {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private CloudFolder parent;  

// Getter and Setter
}
```

Folder Repository:

```
public interface CloudFolderRepository extends JpaRepository<CloudFolder, Integer> {

    CloudFolder findByParentId(Integer id);

    @Transactional
    void deleteByParentId(Integer id);

}
```

Picture of my Folder Table here:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring - No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32269192/spring-no-entitymanager-with-actual-transaction-available-for-current-thread)

Comment: edited my question, this not solved my problem

Comment: I'd say that error speaks for itself. Think about how the FK is set up. Also always post the exact setup you are using and not some old version

Comment: Have you tried cascading on the DB level? Alos which DB do you use?